# Why doesn't two collect function not work in the same suspended function?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

A repository with two data source (local and remote), I am requesting to fetch accessToken on initialization from both soruces. Both function from local and remote return a Flow which I am trying to collect in the initialization. But only the first collect runs successfully and not the other. Why is that? And is there a clean way of handling such use case?

```
    private suspend fun init() {
        refreshAccessTokenFromLocal()
        refreshAccessTokenFromNetwork()
    }
    
    private suspend fun refreshAccessTokenFromNetwork() {
        networkDataSource.refreshAccessToken()
            .collect { accessToken ->
                Timber.d("Debug: refreshing accessToken from network $accessToken")
                localDataSource.updateAccessToken(accessToken)
            }
    }

    private suspend fun refreshAccessTokenFromLocal() {
        localDataSource.getAccessToken().collect { accessToken ->
            Timber.d("Debug: refreshing accessToken from local $accessToken")
            accessTokenAsStateFlow.value = accessToken
        }
    }
```

Comment: It could be the Flow implementation. Does the first Flow ever complete? A Flow can be designed to be finite or infinite until canceled. If you only want one value from a Flow, you can use `first()` instead of `collect()`, and then it won't run forever if the Flow is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

The `collect()` function doesn't launch something in the background. It "blocks" the current coroutine until the flow completes. That's why you only see the first flow being collected.

If you just want to take a value from each flow and use it you can call `first()` on each flow. However, than would probably be not optimal since you would be performing the operations sequentially.

You could also do:

```
coroutineScope {
    val fromNetwork = async { networkDataSource.refreshAccessToken().first() }
    val fromLocal = async { localDataSource.getAccessToken().first() }

    localDataSource.updateAccessToken(fromNetwork.await())
    accessTokenAsStateFlow.value = fromLocal.await()
}
```